# Консоль выдает POST 500 (Internal Server Error) при отправке данных

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть некий опрос, по нажатию на кнопку "Завершить тест", собирается количество правитьных ответов пользователя и ложится в переменную в js. Затем Ajax берет это значение и передает его php, который в свою очередь отправляет в базу данных. Так вот, по нажатию по кнопку консоль пишет что ошибка POST 500 (Internal Server Error), а Ajax что Данные не отправлены. Код вроде бы правильный, но ничего не отправляется. Но если удалить php код, то Ajax выводит в консоль что данные отправлены. Прошу вашей помощи.

php код

```
<?php
$userPoints = $_POST['newUserPoints'];

$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$password = md5($password.'afm430fx0a');

include 'connect.php';

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`points`) VALUES('$userPoints')");

$mysql->close();

header("Location: /");
```

Ajax код

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkBtn', function(){
    let newUserPoints = getCookie('points');

    $.ajax({
        url: '../js/updateDB.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: newUserPoints, 
        success: function(){
            console.log('Данные отправлены! ' + newUserPoints);
        }, 
        error: function() {
            console.log('Данные не отправлены!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "Код вроде бы правильный" --- то есть ошибка 500 это правильный код? Тогда всё работает как нужно....

Comment: И я тебя уже направлял на статьи как находить ошибки и в чём конкретно проблема. Читай заново

Comment: в данном случае скорее всего запрос SQL некорректный

Comment: Алексей, я прочитал как находить ошибки, но мне оно не помогло поэтому я и обратился сюда что бы люди ткнули и помогли разобраться с проблемой так как я только изучаю php и Ajax

Comment: Значит плохо читал. Перечитай заново. **Все ответы**..... Там указано **ВСЁ**, что нужно, чтобы найти как минимум место ошибки и выявить конкретное её наименование.